# Firebase storage rules, leave on path open

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Now that firebase has forced using rules scrambling to find the right solution here.
I have all images in the main bucket and every user once logged in has something like
bucket

```
users/{uid}/uploads
```

where all there uploaded photos go (would be cool to restrict to images at some point)
these should be public read and write, if write can be only for the authenticated user even better, but auth to read is necessary.

there is a special folder before a user is authenticated and need upload a profile pic

`users/uploads`

which should be read write to the public here is what i have but the second rule takes precedence

```
 service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users {
        match /uploads {
            match /object {
            allow read, write
            }
        }
        }
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking it probably needs to be a not /users/uploads forthen then do do this but the documentation is bad for if else statements. any thoughts?

EDIT: this rule set works for reading correctly but still can't write when unauthenticated during sign up

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    
    // Allow only authenticated users to upload
    // Any user can read
    match /users/uploads {
      allow read, write;
    }
  
    // Only allow user with auth.uid == uid to read/write
    match /users/{uid}/uploads {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following rules that'll restrict access to user's own directory and also have a public folder:

```
rules_version="2";
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {

    // Allow only authenticated users to upload
    // Any user can read
    match /users/uploads {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null; 
    }
    
    // Only allow user with auth.uid == uid to read/write
    match /users/{uid}/uploads {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that `if request.auth != null;` allows everyone write (including delete) so try using `allow create:` only.

Comment: everything under the users slug should be public read private write

Comment: @Brian updated the answer. You just need to define read rule separately

Comment: The second rule definitely works while authenticated, I think ill have to change the flow of the app though ie you cant upload an image until you're authenticated, the first rule will still fail as the user is not authenticated

Comment: @Brian where you are trying to upload image when not authenticated? Can you share the opath?

Comment: just users/uploads stores profile pics because they create them during sign up

Comment: I edited the first question with what I assume would work but I still think the second rule overrides the first, I can't upload to /users/uploads peroid